# Draw line between two game objects using linerenderer and raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I'm trying to do is draw line between two gameobjects I'm using ray distance and line renderer but the line is too long. Below is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLineTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    public LineRenderer lineRender;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lineRender = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                lineRender.enabled = true;

                lineRender.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
                lineRender.SetPosition(1, Vector3.down * hit.distance);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure about multiplying 'Vector3.down * hit.distance' ?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik not sure. I'm experimenting and don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: i got either no idea what values you have there, try to remove multiplying, and for instance: change multiplying with addition, for example: `Vector3.down + hit.distance` instead of `Vector3.down * hit.distance` and check if lane length will change. You have to learn how to debug or to provide minimal reproducable example here.

Comment: sorry I mislook on that part I tried using addition but got an error saying "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'float'"

Comment: A guess but can you use `hit.point` instead of `Vector3.down * hit.distance`? unity docs says `The impact point in world space where the ray hit the collider.`

Comment: Why not `lineRender.SetPosition(1, hit.point);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second point is

```
lineRender.SetPosition(1, transform.position + Vector3.down * hit.distance);
```

or

```
lineRender.SetPosition(1, ray.GetPoint(hit.distance));
```

or more succinct

```
lineRender.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
```